Example of super-luminal phase velocity and why wave front velocity as opposed to phase/group velocity pertains to causality
As the title suggests, I have heard that phase velocity of a wave traveling in media could exceed the speed of light and become super-luminal, whereas some people claim that group velocity cannot. However, I have two questions regarding this matter:

What are examples of super-luminal phase velocities, if any?
According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.1856, the wave front velocity should be the one abiding by the universal speed limit, not the phase velocity OR the group velocity at that. In other words, the wave front velocity is what is relevant when it comes to conforming to or violating causality. The logic is that for information to propagate, one could imagine how wave fronts travel through space-time, which could be modeled with a Heaviside $\Theta (x)$ function, which includes frequencies up to infinite. A sufficiently big frequency waves acts as if it is only surrounded by vaccua in any media. Therefore, for the high-frequency waves to catch up, the signal can only travel at the speed of light (if it is an electromagnetic wave). If this is the logic, why then did people claim that group velocity is what decides violation or non-violation of causality?

Thanks in advance, and I hope you all have a great day, whoever stumbled upon this interesting but perplexing topic.

The only “rule” is that you can’t send information along spacelike curves  (curves that travel faster than light in flat spacetime).

This 3blue1brown video might help - But why would light "slow down"?

In short, this is not true, you can have superluminal group velocities while still preserving causality. Consider the dispersion relation $k(\omega)$. Equivalently, this gives the phase velocity:
$$
v_\phi = \frac{\omega}{k(\omega)}
$$
or group velocity:
$$
v_g = \frac1{dk/d\omega}
$$
These are all equivalent formulations by algebraic manipulations and integration/differentiation.
The wave front, i.e. the Green's function, is a bit more involved:
$$
G = \int e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}
$$
By inverse Fourier transform, you can just as well extract the dispersion relation from the wave front.
Indeed, causality applies to the wave front. The elementary definition is ($c=1$):
$$
G(x,t)\propto H(t-x)
$$
Since you can extract from it the dispersion relation from $G$, this will necessarily lead to constraints in the group velocity. However, it is not as simple as just restricting it to subluminal group velocities. This condition is sufficient, but not necessary for causality. The direct translation is that $e^{i(k-\omega)x}$ is analytic in the upper half complex plane ($\Im \omega>0$) and decays to zero at infinity, leading to the Kramers-Kronig relations:
$$
e^{i(k-\omega)x} = \frac1{i\pi}\int\mathcal P\frac{e^{i(k(\omega')-\omega')x}}{\omega'-\omega}d\omega'
$$
The following two examples may help dispel doubts. There are many physical setups where the phase velocity is always superluminal. Take for example a plasma or a mode of a waveguide with dispersion relation ($\omega_0$ is a constant e.g. plasma frequency):
$$
k = \sqrt{\omega^2-\omega_0^2}
$$
However, in this example, the group velocity is always subluminal and the wave front is causal.
An example where you have superluminal group velocities is a medium with an optical resonance (Stellmeier equation):
$$
k = \omega\sqrt{\frac{n_0^2-(\omega/\omega_0)^2}{1-(\omega/\omega_0)^2}}
$$
For $n_0<1$, you even have superluminal group velocities in entire ranges of frequencies like around $\omega=0$. However, the wave front still verifies causality (which you can check by analycity).
A more explicit link between the wavefront and group velocities is when looking at asymptotics via the stationary phase. Estimating $G$ at large times and distances such that $x = vt$ with $v$ fixed and $t\to\infty$ is a classic application of this method. Typically, you would expect:
$$
G(vt,t) \asymp \sum_{\omega_0} e^{i(k(\omega_0)v-\omega_0)t}
$$
where:
$$
v_g(\omega_0) = v
$$
This is why if the group velocity is always subluminal, you do not have these leading order terms outside of the light cone, and your wave front is necessarily causal. However, as the last example illustrates, it is not necessary.
On a side not, the 3B1B video (linked in the comments) gives an appealing but ultimately incorrect argument for causality. It is not enough to have a causal susceptibility to guarantee subluminal wave fronts. A dispersionless medium is a simple counter example.
